# Do any subnets "Network ID" AKA "Network Address" always have an even number as the last octet?

Tags: ipv4, subnet, ip-address

Should a subnet have a **"Network ID"** AKA **"Network Address"** (eg: the first address, which is always unusable, and is the boundary between the previous subnet and the current subnet) always have an even number as the 4th IPv4 octet?

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains about that.

Comment: /32 and /31 are real, legal prefixes.